# Java Generics and Collections

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a question about Java Generics and Collections.  It's considered good practice to declare a collection like this:

```
List<String> catNames = new ArrayList<String>();
```

because you can change the type of the `List` and not worry about breaking the rest of your code.  But when I try to do this:

```
private static Map<IssueType, List<Issue>> orphanedAttrMap = new HashMap<IssueType, ArrayList<Issue>>();
```

`javac` complains

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<ResultsAggregator.IssueType,ArrayList<Issue>> to HashMap<ResultsAggregator.IssueType,List<Issue>>
```

Moreover, this is perfectly legal:

```
private static Map<IssueType, List<Issue>> orphanedAttrMap = new HashMap<IssueType, List<Issue>>();
```

which seems even more confusing, because `List` is an interface, not a concrete class.  What's going on here?  Is this a type erasure issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it was legal to compile such a code, you would've been able to sneakily insert element of other types in the `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<IssueType, List<Issue>> a = new HashMap<IssueType, ArrayList<Issue>>();
a.put(someIssue, new SomeClassThatImplementsListOfIssueButIsNotArrayList());
```

which is not what you expect. `ArrayList<String>` is a `List<String>`, but that's not enough for this code to be safe and correct. To be safe, it also requires `List<String>` to be `ArrayList<String>`, which means the generic type argument is not covariant here.

Your last code is legal because nothing requires the type parameter to be a concrete class.  Similarly, nothing requires a field to be of an abstract type.

Comment: But isn't that also true in the first case where it's considered 'good practice' ?

Comment: @Amir: No, it's not.  The first line declares a single variable of type `List<Issue>`.  If you assign some other list to that variable later, you are replacing the instance completely.  You are not changing something *inside* the `ArrayList`.  There's no way you could do something bad with that line.

Answer (score 4):

There is not reason to specify an ArrayList in your second example.  It doesn't actually create a list so it is best to put the interface in there anyway.  You will later then able able to call the following just fine.

```
Map<IssueType, List<Issue>> orphanedAttrMap = new HashMap<IssueType, List<Issue>>();

orphanedAttrMap.put(IssueType.TYPE, new ArrayList<Issue>());
```

Comment: Is this the better approach, or is it better to declare the LHS as ArrayList<Issue> ?

Comment: @Amir, this is the better approach unless the code that uses this map relies on something from ArrayList that is not a part of the List interface (say, ensureCapacity()). And even then you better leave it as List and use `if (... instanceof ...)` and downcasting to access the ArrayList methods where it is really necessary. Using interfaces is almost always better than using concrete classes.